# Sencha Touch Combo Box using Model and Store

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have this on model

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.job', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
alias: 'model.job',

config: {
    fields: [{
        name: 'name',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'value',
        type: 'string'
    }]
}
```

});

And this on store

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.job', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
alias: 'store.job',

requires: [
    'MyApp.model.job'
],

config: {
    autoLoad: true,

    data: [
    {
        name: '--Please Select--',
        value: ''
    }, {
        name: 'Job 1',
        value: 'Job1'
    }, {
        name: 'Job 2',
        value: 'Job2'
    }, {
        name: 'Job 3',
        value: 'Job3'
    }
    ],

    model: 'MyApp.model.job',
    storeId: 'jobStore'
}
```

});

And this is the View

```
                    {
                    xtype         : 'selectfield',
                    name          : 'job',
                    label         : 'Job',
                    displayField : 'name',
                    valueField : 'value',
                    store: 'jobStore'
                }
```

But I got the following error on Console
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined"

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `job` store, remove the unneccessary line `storeId: 'jobStore'` and in the view edit store to `store: 'job'` and your code will be working fine.
Beside this, i would ask you to remove few line of code from your snippet(Because in standard Sencha coding, we follow certain rules).

1. `requires: [
   'MyApp.model.job'
   ],`
2. `alias: 'store.job'`
3. `alias: 'model.job'`

Happy coding. :)

### EDIT

In app.js of your application, you should write

```
models: ['job'],

stores: ['job']
```

instead model and store.

Comment: Have you removed the storeId from store? I have imitated your issue on my side. But when removing the storeId, the problem gets solved.

Comment: Yes, I followed your 3 comments above. Btw, do we need controller for this? I don't have one. Only model, store and view.

Comment: Actually not 3 comments only! Above that there is main thing: storeId: 'jobStore', which you have to remove(whether you remove the points 1, 2 and 3 or not). And still if you face any problem, put your code in senchafiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2rk , i will see what is the issue.

Comment: Oh yes I followed those too. Oh no sorry I cannot even use sencha fiddle. How to add mvc structure there? All I can see only one app.js there.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_2iAtL95dUfVW90ejU5WUlhRkk&usp=sharing if you are interested looking at this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whew... You were doing blunder. In app.js, you should write models: [
        'job'
    ],
    
    stores: [
        'job'
    ]. That is it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'm so dumb. Now I can run until the layout appears. No more error on the console. But the selectfield is still not loading. It shows nothing there just empty.

Comment: Add displayField : 'name', valueField : 'value', in your selectfield view.

Comment: OMG, that's did the job. Thanks!